# SSRS Graph not showing in IOS 10

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS subscription report that sends an email with a graph at the bottom of the email. The delivery method is MHTML. I've had this job running for a few years now. I just noticed that the graph/chart does not show on the email if the iphone user has ios10. I've tested with other users that have ios9 and it works fine. Any ideas? or anybody else having this issue?

Comment: maybe post this on the [dba stack exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: FWIW - SSRS converts charts into pics (PNG) when sent as MHTML. Does IOS 10 have issue with PNGs? (I don't have any IOS stuff so IDK)

Comment: jkdba - will post it on dba stack exchange also